# IntrinsicAttributes props in React Typescript component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I have this message alert:

> The type '{ children: string; notify: string; }' cannot be assigned to
> type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { notify: any; }'.   Property 'children'
> does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { notify: any;
> }'.ts(2322)

using Card component. This is the first time I get it.

this is the component:

```
const Card = (props:{notify:any}) => {
 
  if (props.notify.length> 0> 0){
    return <IonIcon icon={notifications}  id="iconoHomeCampana">  </IonIcon>

  }else{
    return <IonIcon icon={notificationsOff}  id="iconoHomeCampana">  </IonIcon>
  }
}


export interface newMessage{
  de:string
  ticket:string
}

const App= () => {

  const [notifications, setNotifications] =  useState < newMessage []> ( [])

  useEffect(() => {

  axios.get(url+"chatsinleer/"+props.email).then((resp: { data: any; }) => {
      if (resp.data!="bad"){
        setNotifications(resp.data.map((d: { de: any; ticket: any; }) => ({
          de:d.de,
          ticket:d.ticket,
          })));
      }
    })

  }, []);

return (
      <IonPage >
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonGrid>
              <IonRow id="header">
                <IonCol id="columna" size="1.5"><IonButtons ><IonMenuButton /> </IonButtons></IonCol>
                <IonCol id="columna2" ><Busqueda categorias={categorias} setCategorias={setCategorias} setProveedorBuscadoHook={setProveedorBuscadoHook} setBuscar={setBuscar} /></IonCol>
                <IonCol id="columna3" size="1.5"> 
                  <Card notify={notifications}>  </Card>
                </IonCol>
              </IonRow>
            </IonGrid>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
    )
}
```

Comment: Replace `<Card notify={notifications}>  </Card>` with `<Card notify={notifications}/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete space inside `<Card notify={notifications}>  </Card>`

and use it instead like `<Card notify={notifications}></Card>` or even better like this:

```
<Card notify={notifications}/>
```

Problem is that react perceived space as child element;

Here is simple repro which also gave same error:

```
const Comp1 = ({ a }: { a: boolean }) => {
  return null;
};

const Comp2 = () => {
  return <Comp1 a={true}> </Comp1>;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

**The answer:**

`<Card> </Card>` is the same as `<Card>{" "}</Card>` which means you are sending a space as a child of that component. Replace it for `<Card {...props} />` and that will solve your problem as there won't be any children nodes.

**The explanation:**

JSX Docs:

> JSX removes whitespace at the beginning and ending of a line. It also removes blank lines. New lines adjacent to tags are removed; new lines that occur in the middle of string literals are condensed into a single space.

And [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12270).

Basically, spaces are considered meaningful in JSX, so avoiding them when not needed it's a good practice.

**More nerdy stuff:**

`JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` it's an interface that allows you to globally extend the attributes of JSX nodes, for example, `key` in React.

React does not include the `children` prop in `IntrinsicAttributes` so, when a component needs to render children it is necessary to explicitly add it to the props type definition.

[More info here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

Answer (score 0):

here man

```
interface ISetAuth {
  setAuth: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const Login = ({ setAuth }: ISetAuth) => {

}
```

I struggled for 40min with this... :')